# Disconnect from wifi without disabling interface

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, terminal

For a client project, a part of the application requires me to disconnect the Raspberry Pi from the WiFi. I'm doing this operation using OS commands. To disconnect from the wifi, currently I'm calling the OS command `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` which disables the network interface and the Pi is disconnected.

However, I require the network interface to be active (for certain other activities). Is there a way to do this ? I have access to the wpa_supplicant files, is there a way where I can somehow manipulate this file to disconnect without deleting the user's saved SSID and passwords?

I need to do this from the terminal itself, as the end user will have a different application running in kiosk mode, so he won't be able to access the GUI tools for networks.

Comment: Try using `sudo rfkill block 0`

Comment: Do you really need to disconnect, and why? Can't you just kill the process which uses the network?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I manipulated the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file in the `/etc/wpa_supplicant` folder:

1. Copy the contents of the file to a temporary file. Use some basic string manipulations to extract only the top 3 header lines.
2. Overwrite the original `wpa_supplicant.conf` file with just the headers
3. Execute `wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure`
4. This makes the Pi temporarily forget all networks, and therefore disconnects from the wifi leaving the interface up.
5. When the user is ready to connect again, simply replace the contents of the `wpa_supplicant.conf` with temporary file created earlier and run step 3 again

Note: Always keep a backup of the original `wpa_supplicant.conf` somewhere safe so if things go wrong, you can undo the changes

This method also doesn't touch the wlan0 interface itself, and so is safe as long as the wpa_supplicant.conf contains the headers

Answer (score 2):

##### Preface:

This *"answer"* is in two parts. The first part is my assessment of your question, the second part is a suggestion intended to help you move toward a clearer understanding of your network management toolset, which will hopefully allow you to formulate a clearer question.

##### Part 1:

***N.B. Networking questions can be difficult questions to formulate.***
To put it *bluntly*, your question strikes me as ambiguous and unclear. You speak of *"connected"* and *"disconnected"*, then you say you put the interface `down` (disabled) yet require it to be *"active"* (whatever that is) for *"certain other activities"*.  Think for a moment about what exactly each of those terms mean. I'm sure you'll appreciate that network questions are difficult - for several reasons - when they are clearly stated, but may be near impossible otherwise.

A good and clear network question can be difficult to compose. Stack Exchange recognizes this difficulty; this is why an upvote for a question and and upvote for an answer have the same point rewards. Also, a good and clear question is much more likely to net you a good and clear answer. These are the incentives for investing a bit more time and effort in your question.

##### Part 2:

As distributed, RPi OS uses `wpa_supplicant` and `wpa-cli` as its default "WiFi manager". [`wpa_cli` is said to be a "complete tool"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240707/what-are-the-most-reliable-wifi-commandline-tools-iw-vs-wpa-cli-vs-nmcli) for managing a wi-fi connection set up with `wpa_supplicant`.

Read `man wpa_cli` - or `wpa_cli -help` to learn its options. As stated above, I'm unclear on what you mean when you said, `"I require the network interface to be active (for certain other activities)"`, but perhaps perusing the available documentation will help you revise your question such that it is less ambiguous. For example, see the parameters `enable_network` and `disable_network`.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no other network interfaces active, just stop dhcpcd:

```
sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd
```

This may leave the interface in a DOWN state but you can put it up again:

```
sudo ip l set wlan0 up
```

Whether or not that allows for your "certain other activities" I can't say since I don't know what they are.